# how to change method annotation using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I want to change method annotation using reflection in java

here is a snapshot:

can you suggest?.

```
final List<Method> allMethods = new ArrayList<Method>(Arrays.asList(klass.getDeclaredMethods()));
    Method thisMethod = allMethods.stream().filter(m->m.getName()   == "getWithPathParam" ).findFirst().get();

    Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = thisMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
    for(Annotation[] annotations : parameterAnnotations){
        for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
            if(annotation instanceof ApiParam){
                Annotation newAnnotation = new ApiParam() {
                    @Override
                    public String allowableValues() {
                        return "test";
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
                        return annotation.annotationType();
                    }
                };
```

here I want basically to exchange annotation field with newAnnotation field

it is possible?

Comment: No. Why do you think you need to do this? Annotations are compile-time by their very nature.

Comment: As much as I agree with @EJP , I'm rooting for this question to witness the paradigm shift in java programming.

Comment: because I need that allowableValues return a dynamic value

Comment: If the word 'dynamic' is involved, don't use annotations.